# Which directory spark applications on yarn output their logs to? spark.eventLog.dir or var/log/ in each node?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am building a log analysis planform to monitor spark jobs on a yarn cluster and I want to get a clear idea about spark/yarn logging.
I have searched a lot about this and these are the confusions I have.

1. The directory specified in spark.eventLog.dir or spark.history.fs.logDirectory get stored all the
   application master logs and through log4j.properties in spark conf we can customize those logs ?
2. In default all data nodes output their executor logs to a folder in /var/log/.  with log-aggregation enabled you can get those executer logs to the spark.eventLog.dir location as well?

I've managed to set up a 3 node virtual hadoop yarn cluster, spark installed in the master node. When I'm running spark in client mode I'm thinking this node becomes the application master node.
I'm a beginner to Big data and appreciate any effort to help me out with these confusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark `log4j` logging is written to the Yarn container stderr logs. The directory for these is controlled by `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` configuration parameter (default value on EMR is `/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers`).

(`spark.eventLog.dir` is only used by the Spark History Server to display the Web UI after a job has finished. Here, Spark writes [events that encode the information displayed in the UI to persisted storage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)).

Comment: So it possible to get real time Spark logs from default yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs directory?